# Applet is blocking jquery loading animation

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

In my main page I have an applet that is loaded using the specific tag.
In the same time, when the page is shown I had to implement a jQuery loading animation (the .animate() function is used; some images that 'run' from left to right/top to bottom and a progress bar). The applet is set as hidden and is shown when it is finish loading.

The loading animation works fine but on IE I am facing a problem: the first image that has to slide from left to right either is hidden or it dissapears for a fixed distance; when it must be shown again (second animate) it works ok; the other animations are working correct, even from the first time.

After hours of debugging (setting visible, z-index, move the applet x coordinate,etc)...
I noticed that the problem is in fact the applet itself. If i cut it out from the .jsp, the animation works fine... 
I am thinking that somehow the browser is affected when the applet starts (I use IE9).

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?
I really must load both when the page is shown (the loading animation must be showed until the applet is loaded).

Thank you and regards,
Luisa

Comment: I know this won't help, but nevertheless: There is a good chance, there is little you can do. Browser plugins in general and specifically Java applets are a dying breed. And especially Microsoft was never a friend of Java, so it's no wonder that there are problems with it. You should seriously consider if you really have to use a Java applet. You could use Java Web Start, if it has to be Java, and maybe display your animations within the Java application instead. Or try CSS animations instead of JS animations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have any alternative, I must use applet. You mentioned CSS animations, if I use this, I could make it work? How I can do an animation using CSS? Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not saying it will work with CSS animations. It's just worth a try, because you'll be leaving one factor (JavaScript). Also IE 9 doesn't support them. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations for some basics.